# ElasticSearch: Filter with multiple objects being ignored with Simple_Query_String

Tags: python-2.7, elasticsearch

I am trying to construct a query with two filters.  One can contain a single item or a list of items, while the other can only contain one item.  When I run this combination filter, it seems like the filter is just ignored and it returns a best match on the other columns.  I am using ElasticSearch 6.8 with Python Flask.

animallist could potentially look like [{"match":{"animal_species":"hippo"}}], or 
[{"match":{"animal_species":"lopear"}},{"match":{"animal_species":"Rex"}}]

animal_type would look like {"match":{"animal_type":"Mammal"}} or {"match":{"animal_type":"Bird"}}

It feels like there is something wrong with the animal_type match, because I previously had just the species filter and it worked fine.

```
body={
            'from': (page) * per_page,
             'size': per_page,
             'query':{
                 'bool':{
                     'filter':
                     { 
                        'bool':{
                            'must':{
                                'match':{'animal_type':a_type}},
                                'should':animallist
                                    }
                    },
                     'must':{
                             'simple_query_string':{
                            'query':query,
                            'default_operator': 'AND',
                            'fields': ['*']
                    }
                     }
                     }
                     }
            }
```

My Mapping looks like this

```
{
   "animal_files":{
      "aliases":{

      },
      "mappings":{
         "properties":{
            "animal_type":{
               "type":"text",
               "fields":{
                  "keyword":{
                     "type":"keyword",
                     "ignore_above":256
                  }
               }
            },
            "animal_species":{
               "type":"text",
               "fields":{
                  "keyword":{
                     "type":"keyword",
                     "ignore_above":256
                  }
               }
            },
            "filepath":{
               "type":"text",
               "fields":{
                  "keyword":{
                     "type":"keyword",
                     "ignore_above":256
                  }
               }
            },
            "text":{
               "type":"text",
               "fields":{
                  "keyword":{
                     "type":"keyword",
                     "ignore_above":256
                  }
               }
            },
            "case_title":{
               "type":"text",
               "fields":{
                  "keyword":{
                     "type":"keyword",
                     "ignore_above":256
                  }
               }
            },
            "case_number":{
               "type":"text",
               "fields":{
                  "keyword":{
                     "type":"keyword",
                     "ignore_above":256
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.  I changed the match for animal_type to a match_phrase.  After doing some reading, I think the analyzer was tokenizing each letter in the match query.